# Empty space for ads between “Questions tagged” title and the description of the tag

Tags: bug, design, advertising

In Google Chrome, I always see an empty space between the title of “Questions tagged” and the description of the tag, an you can see it here:

[image: There is a large empty gap between the title and the tag description of about five times the line height of the title. It has been highlighted with a red stroke.]

and here:

[image: This shows another such example, but with a different tag.]

I think this space is reserved for ads. Is this a possible bug?

I’m using the latest Google Chrome version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: @user4642212 I do use some anti-virus extensions and I think this is the cause of this problem and yes, when I block them, every thing work fine

Comment: I just realized that there’s _something_ that I see when I enable “Show me more advertisements” in my preferences. If I also disable uBlock Origin (on Firefox Nightly 79.0a1), I only _briefly_ see this empty space before it disappears. I now also see it on Google Chrome, same version as yours (apparently I missed it, or expected it to last permanently). I’m deleting my first, obsolete comment.

Comment: By the way, you can check if the space is reserved for ads yourself by inspecting the elements in your browser: [there’s something that contains `google_ads_iframe`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq31G.png) — it’s definitely reserved for ads.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I don't see any empty space in Chrome 64-bit 83.0.4103.61 (haven't updated yet...).

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think it related with the version, but with extension that we install. for me, when I disable some  extension, I can't see this problem

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Stack Overflow, but if I go to a site like Electronics.SE where I have less rep, then I see content jumping on question pages (e.g., [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507566/how-to-set-oscilloscope-for-measurement-of-interrupt-service-routine-execution-t)). It looks like it's trying to load an ad banner, but then suppressing it. I imagine the same thing is happening on the tag pages for you on SO. (I have < 200 rep on EE.SE.) I have Chrome, but no ad-blocking extensions.

Comment: @CodyGray Have you enabled the “Show me more advertisements” option in your account preferences?

Comment: @user4642212 I have the "Do not show me more ads" option enabled on my SO profile. There is no such option on my EE.SE profile, because I do not have enough rep there to opt out of ads.