# Jumping screen on tag's page after load

Tags: bug, design

After [tag's page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) loaded, it unexpectedly "jumps" in browser viewport.

This is known as bad practice: https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/

Additionally, this jump doesn't make any sense, as it doesn't add any content to the page itself. It's caused by empty area that got hidden after load.

Biggest downside of this bug is when you in the middle of the page, click on some question and then use browser Back button, your can't see this whitespace removed, but you see massive content shift, which is frustrating.

Bug record:

[image]

Note: make sure you don't have any browser extensions activated to reproduce the bug.

Comment: As much as I hate content jumping and agree with you that it's a serious anti-pattern, I think it's actually the fault of your ad blocker in this case. I cannot reproduce the behavior that you describe.

Comment: This has been reported here: [Empty space for ads between “Questions tagged” title and the description of the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398058/empty-space-for-ads-between-questions-tagged-title-and-the-description-of-the). Quoting my comment: _“I only_ briefly _see this empty space before it disappears”_.

Comment: @CodyGray edited: added note that you need turn off all browser extensions to reproduce the bug

Comment: @user4642212 that support question is related, but content shift is what my post about, so it should be reviewed as bug report

Comment: Please include browser, OS, and versions of both. For instance, I don't see this in Microsoft Edge Version 85.0.552.1 (Official build) dev (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise Version 10.0.18362.778.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if you have adblocker, you won't see it

Comment: I didn't have any extensions enabled when I tested.